# Question regarding declensions in Dativ

Tags: dative, declension

Sentence: Ich fliege mit meiner ganzen Familie nach München.

Question: When we are declining the words before "Familie" (in Dativ), I can understand why "mein" becomes "meiner" - because of the Dativ declension for the feminine noun Familie, but why does "ganz" become "ganzen" and not "ganzer" in the same way as "meiner"? Any help would be greatly appreciated :)

Comment: I just added an [English explanation link](https://www.germanveryeasy.com/adjective-declension) to the answer of the referred question.

Comment: Thanks a lot :) now I get it